# Capturing PCM audio data stream into file, and playing stream via ffmpeg, how?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, gstreamer, audio-recording

Would like to do following four things (separately), and need a bit of help understanding how to approach this,

1. Dump audio data (from a serial-over-USB port), encoded as PCM, 16-bit, 8kHz, little-endian, into a file (plain binary data dump, not into any container format). Can this approach be used:

   $ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > somefile.dat

Can I do a ^C to close the file writing, while the dumping is in progress, as per the above command ?

2. Stream audio data (same as above described kind), directly into ffmpeg for it to play out ? Like this:

   $ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | ffmpeg

or, do I have to specify the device port as a "-source" ? If so, I couldn't figure out the format.

Note that, I've tried this,

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | aplay
```

which works as expected, by playing out white-noise..., but trying the following doesn't help:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyUSB1 | aplay -f S16_LE
```

Even though, opening /dev/ttyUSB1 using picocom @ 115200bps, 8-bit, no parity, I do see gibbrish, indicating presence of audio data, exactly when I expect.

3. Use the audio data dumped into the file, use as a source in ffmpeg ? If so how, because so far I get the impression that ffmpeg can read a file in standard containers.
4. Use pre-recorded audio captured in any format (perhaps .mp3 or .wav) to be streamed by ffmpeg, into /dev/ttyUSB0 device. Should I be using this as a "-sink" parameter, or pipe into it or redirect into it ? Also, is it possible that in 2 terminal windows, I use ffmpeg to capture and transmit audio data from/into same device /dev/ttyUSB0, simultaneously ?

My knowledge of digital audio recording/processing formats, codecs is somewhat limited, so not sure if what I am trying to do qualifies as working with 'raw' audio or not ?

If ffmpeg is unable to do what I am hoping to achieve, could gstreamer be the solution ?

*PS> If anyone thinks that the answer could be improved, please feel free to suggest specific points. Would be happy to add any detail requested, provided I have the information.*

Comment: To the one who's voted to close, kindly lookup the 'ffmpeg' tag, and I'm sure you'd find that most of ffmpeg questions are not directly programming related. They are often precursor to a programmed implementation. It is my intention to program the read of serial port and control of device via Python, but prior to that, I need to know how to interact. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: First step would be open `somefile.dat` using audacity and check there if you can play it, and if you get a good looking wave view. BTW, I think your question is too broad.